# Ionic 2 e One Signal como usar a função handleNotificationOpened()

Tags: javascript, ionic2, typescript, api

Tenho um aplicativo que está 90% pronto, as notificações já estão configuradas com o One Signal, porém, eu quero enviar o usuário pra uma página especifica quando ele clicar na notificação, e essa página pode ser diferente dependendo da notificação que eu enviar. Exemplo: Mando uma notificação sobre Saldo da Conta, eu mando ele pra página de saldo, se eu mandar uma notificação sobre upgrade, mando pra uma página de upgrade. Todos os exemplos que eu vi na documentação estão em Java. Aqui está o código do Onesignal:

```
InitializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  setTimeout(() => { this._SplashScreen.hide(); }, 3000);
  this._OneSignal.startInit("99bb8873-4807-44c6-871f-7c3711201e34", "153883364067");
  this._OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this._OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
  this._OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
  this._OneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
    // handle received here how you wish.
  });
  this._OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
    // handle opened here how you wish.
  });
  this._OneSignal.endInit();
});
```

}

Preciso usa o handleNotificationOpened() pra customizar a página de destino do usuario dentro do meu aplicativo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dessa forma vc recebe os valores enviados pelo One Signal e consegue tratar com os dados recebidos.

```
this._OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(data);
});
```